# how ed=1 in RSA cryptosystem?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I fully understand the how the RSA algorithm works, but now I am trying to reason with the formula. I want to know:

why the public key e and the private key d in the RSA encryption have to satisfy the equation ed = 1 mod (p − 1)(q − 1)?

Is it because of the standard modular arithmetic rule where 1 mod anything is 1, or is there a more to this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a message called **x** and you want to encrypt it with your public key **(pq, e)**. If you encrypt **x**, you get **x^e mod pq**. Someone who knows **d** can get **x^(ed) mod pq**.
Because **ed = 1 mod (p - 1)(q - 1)**, by Fermat's little theorem, we get that **x^(ed) mod pq = x**, thus decrypting the message. If **ed != 1 mod (p - 1)(q - 1)**, then the message could not be decrypted.

A link to Fermat's little theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem